# Do something if variable matches pattern "title=*"

Tags: php, regex

```
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "title=*") {echo 'do something!';}
```

This code does not function as I had hoped. Is there a simple method to:

```
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "title=/*ANYTHING*/") {echo 'do something!';}
```

Comment: start by counting your `(` and `)`. They should match

Comment: Oh brother. That simple error is why everyone is so upset?

Comment: `==` performs exact matching, it doesn't look for patterns or wildcards. Use `preg_match()` to perform regular expression pattern matching.

Comment: Probably more robust to inspect the query string in PHP by looking at `$_GET['title']` and in this instance, `if(isset($_GET['title']))`

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$pos = strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'title=');
if ($pos === 0) {
    // do something
}
```

`strpos` returns `false` if it can't find the string, otherwise the position it found it in.

In your case, that position needs to be `0` (note the `===`)

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for the right syntax for hours.